# regex to replace HTML sorrounding tag

Tags: regex

im trying to replace an html tag with another one using notepad++ search and replace.
i would like this:

```
<strong style="font-size: 1em;"><br />some text</strong>
```

to become this

```
<h3>some text</h3>
```

so far i have reached this:

```
<strong style="font-size: 1em;"\s(.*?)><br />(.*?)</strong>
```

and am not sure what to put inside "replace with", is this ok:

```
 <h3>$1</h3>
```

?

Thanks

Comment: it's ok if it works for you :)

Comment: true but it didn't find the pattern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex should be this for catching...

```
<strong style="font-size: 1em;"\s?(.*?)><br />(.*?)</strong>
```

this `\s` should be optional according to your html

Comment: looks like this is correct.it found and replaced the pattern. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this as the replacement pattern.

```
<h3>\2</h3>
```

You can reference capture groups (between parenthesis) in the regex by \n where n is the number of the group.